# Story About a Statue in a Museum

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I have this vague and nagging memory of reading a short story about a man who goes into a museum at night to examine an extremely large statue; if memory serves the statue is really either alive  or a kind of robot.  I know that's not a lot, but it's all I've got! Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might be thinking of **["Farewell to the Master"](https://web.archive.org/web/20140727101426/http://thenostalgialeague.com/olmag/bates-farewell-to-the-master.html)** by **Harry Bates**. (If you click on the title, it will lead you to the text of the story.) The story was first published in *Astounding Science Fiction* (October 1940) and is credited with having inspired the 1951 science fiction movie *The Day the Earth Stood Still,* and thus the 2008 "remake" with the same title, although neither film was entirely faithful to the original plot.

As the story opens, we learn that about three months ago an alien spacecraft landed and two entities walked out of it. One was a humanoid called Klaatu, and the other was a large robot called Gnut. Klaatu obviously wanted to be friendly (he spoke excellent English while introducing himself and his companion), but he was soon shot by a lunatic who somehow thought Klaatu was the devil. Klaatu died on the spot. His body was rushed to a hospital, but it did no good. Gnut, on the other hand, became absolutely motionless from that moment onward. (Or so it was believed.) Accordingly, a museum was quickly built on and around the spot where Klaatu died and where Gnut was still standing.

However, the viewpoint character has become convinced that Gnut is not quite so immobile as everyone seems to assume. Here's a passage from the story which might jog your memory (if this is, in fact, what you once read):

> The recorded voice ceased speaking. Cliff, carefully moving his
>   cramped limbs, broke out in a wide smile. If they knew what he knew!
>
> For his photographs told a slightly different story from that of the
>   lecturer.  In yesterday's a line of the figured floor showed clearly
>   at the outer edge of the robot's near foot; in today's, that line was
>   covered. Gnut had moved!
>
> Or been moved, though this was very unlikely. Where was the derrick
>   and other evidence of such activity? It could hardly have been done in
>   one night, and all signs so quickly concealed. And why should it be
>   done at all?
>
> Still, to make sure, he had asked the guard. He could almost remember
>   verbatim his answer:
>
> "No, Gnut has neither moved nor been moved since the death of his
>   master. A special point was made of keeping him in the position he
>   assumed at Klaatu's death. The floor was built in under him, and the
>   scientists who completed his derangement erected their apparatus
>   around him, just as he stands. You need have no fears."
>
> Cliff smiled again. He did not have any fears.

I won't ruin the ending for you -- what I've already said, plus the link that will let you read the entire thing, ought to be enough to help you decide whether or not this is the old story which you vaguely remembered. If you've forgotten the details of the ending you once read, I wouldn't want to deprive you of having that experience all over again!

Comment: That's it!  My nagging mind can rest. Many thanks for the quick response; I'll enjoy re-reading it after all these years!

Comment: Glad I could help. About a year ago, I arrived on this site under similar circumstances. I was trying to remember the title and author of a science fiction story which I'd read before, and enjoyed, but couldn't find again. (I also wanted to check out the author's other work, if I hadn't already.) Someone came up with the correct answer pretty quickly, and I've stuck around since then, sometimes answering other people's story-identifcation questions when they describe something that suddenly rings a bell in my own memory!

Comment: Thanks again! I just reread the story; fortunately my imperfect memory in this instance became an asset, because I was able to enjoy it all over again. Many thanks!